# Create simple ExtJS form

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

I'm trying to create a very simple modal form with Ext JS 2.3.0. The code I'm using is:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ext-all.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dash.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all-debug-TPF-212.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function () {

    var entitySearchForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        title: "Basic Form",
        width: 425,
        frame: true,
        items: [
        new Ext.form.TextField({
            hideLabel: true,
            width: 275,
            allowBlank: false
        })],
        buttons: [{
            text: "Save"
        }]
    });

    var entitySearchWindow = new Ext.Window({
        layout: 'anchor',
        closable: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        items: [entitySearchForm]
    });

    entitySearchWindow.show();
});
</script>

</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

This causes the following form to appear:

[image]

There are a couple of problems with this:

- The save button doesn't look like a button (though it does behave like one). I want the save button to look like a button, have a width of about 100px and appear to the right of the text box (instead of underneath it)
- there are two short narrow stripes, one on either side of the text field. How can I get rid of these?
- The form doesn't have a close button, even though I specified `closable: true`

I realise I'm using quite an old version of Ext JS, but unfortunately upgrading is not an option right now.

Comment: 2.3.0? You have my sympathies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running without dash.css. In my tests with just ext-all.css, the stripes are gone, the close button appears, and the save button looks like a button.

As for the location of the save button, the FormPanel uses the form layout by default. By using table layout instead, and making the save button an item the button shows up next to the textfield:

```
var entitySearchForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({

    title: "Basic Form",
    layout:'table',
    width: 425,
    frame: true,
    layoutConfig: {columns: 3},
    items: [
    new Ext.form.TextField({
        hideLabel: true,
        width: 275,
        colspan: 2,
        allowBlank: false
    }), {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Save',
        handler: function() {/* submit code */}
    }]
});`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, table layout works a lot better. Do you know if it's possible to get a small space between the text field and the button so that they're not squashed up against each other?

Comment: I don't know if it is available in 2.3, but in 3.4 the `layoutConfig` for table layout has a property, `tableAttrs`, that looks like it allows cellpadding and other properties to be specified. Also, a cell-specific CSS class can be specified in `cellCls`. See: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.layout.TableLayout